# Can we use docker-image with the hyperkit driver on a mac?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I've installed the Docker Mac Beta - and would like to spin up a new docker-machine using what I think would be the "hyperkit" driver.  Can I do that?

And why don't I see my hyperkit created "default" docker-machine when I run `docker-machine ls`?

Is this just a beta issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, NO. Read [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#/docker-toolbox-and-docker-for-mac-coexistence) to understand how they can coexist on same machine but you can't use docker-machine to manage HyperKit VM, spun up by Docker for Mac.